# Combine two lists in to a single tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[5,6,7,8]
```

My expected Tuple should look like

```
C=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

How can I combine these lists into my desired output?

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. You need to show some effort on your own.

Comment: Ask your teacher? Google it? Search around on this site. So many good options if you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as:

```
tuple(A + B)
```

Which results in:

> ```
> >>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> >>> B = [5, 6, 7, 8]
> >>> print(tuple(A + B))
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
> ```

It wasn't as hard as you thought, was it ? Just [**have a look at the docs**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before asking here.

Comment: LOL.  That was easy!!